# ¿Es necesario crear los modelos para las tablas de la base de datos? Laravel 5.1

Tags: sql, laravel-5, laravel

Me surgió le siguiente duda, en un proyecto que estoy haciendo tengo un alrededor de 25 tablas para mi base de datos. Mi archivo .sql ya esta listo con las tablas y quiero saber si tengo que crear un modelo en Laravel para cada tabla, lo quiero saber porque sería un trabajo un poco cansado ya que en mi sql ya estan mis relaciones directamente y no quiero hacer relación por relación desde 0. O también si hay alguna forma de que el Laravel me cree esas relaciones directamente.

Comment: A qué te refieres con crear las relaciones directamente?

Comment: Recuerda que en los modelos uno puede hacer las relaciones, por ejemplo uno a uno, uno a mucho o muchos a muchos. Bueno, Laravel nos da la opción de en nuestro modelo poner 
 public function phone() { 
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone'); 
}
Algo así la relación, yo tengo la relación hechas en mi sql y no se si tengo que agregar esas mismas funciones en mi modelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondiendo a la pregunta como tal, NO es necesario crear los modelos para cada tabla, todo depende del diseño de tu aplicación, la ventaja de tener los modelos es tener las relaciones precargadas como propiedades y los métodos que ofrecen dichas relaciones, lo cual va a ahorrar cientos o miles de líneas de código.

No todas las tablas necesitan un modelo, como las de pivote o las polimórficas.

Hay algunos paquetes como Eloquent model generator y Laravel model generator que te pueden ayudar a generar modelos y relaciones a partir de un esquema de base de datos, pero no sé qué tan buenos sean, no los he usado.

Comment: Al parecer el "Eloquent model generator" cumple con lo que pido, lo probaré.